# How to get rid of empty line in python output

Tags: python-3.6

My code looks like this:

```
def main():
    def say_words1():
        print("Welcome​ ​to​ ​Madame​ ​Maxine's​ ​Fortune​ ​Palace.")
   `    print("Here,​ ​we​ ​gaze​ ​deeply​ ​into​ ​your​ ​soul​ ​and​ ​find​ ​the") 
        print("secrets​ ​that​ ​only​ ​destiny​ ​has​ ​heretofore​ ​known!")
        print("                                               ")
        print("The​ ​power​ ​of​ ​my​ ​inner​ ​eye​ ​clouds​ ​my​ ​ability​ ​to​ ​keep")
        print("track​ ​of​ ​mundane​ ​things​ ​like​ ​the​ ​date."), 
    say_words1()
    def get_today(the_date):
        the_date=input("Tell​ ​me,​ ​what​ ​day​ ​of​ ​the​ ​month​ ​is​ ​it​ ​today: ")
    get_today("the_date")
main()
```

the output looks like this:

```
Welcome​ ​to​ ​Madame​ ​Maxine's​ ​Fortune​ ​Palace.
Here,​ ​we​ ​gaze​ ​deeply​ ​into​ ​your​ ​soul​ ​and​ ​find​ ​the
secrets​ ​that​ ​only​ ​destiny​ ​has​ ​heretofore​ ​known!

The​ ​power​ ​of​ ​my​ ​inner​ ​eye​ ​clouds​ ​my​ ​ability​ ​to​ ​keep
track​ ​of​ ​mundane​ ​things​ ​like​ ​the​ ​date.

Tell​ ​me,​ ​what​ ​day​ ​of​ ​the​ ​month​ ​is​ ​it​ ​today: 5
```

How do i get rid of the line between track of... and Tell me...  ?
I am using python 3.6

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (I took the liberty to suggest some editing - what is that comma at the end of `say_words1()`?)

Comment: I've fixed formatting of output, to make the problem clear.

Comment: After deleting the odd floating `\``, I don't see a line there with my Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the problem is that one, but I could not reproduce the extra unwanted newline with the code below:

```
def main():
    def say_words1():
        print("Welcome​ ​to​ ​Madame​ ​Maxine's​ ​Fortune​ ​Palace.")
        print("Here,​ ​we​ ​gaze​ ​deeply​ ​into​ ​your​ ​soul​ ​and​ ​find​ ​the")
        print("secrets​ ​that​ ​only​ ​destiny​ ​has​ ​heretofore​ ​known!\n")
        print("The​ ​power​ ​of​ ​my​ ​inner​ ​eye​ ​clouds​ ​my​ ​ability​ ​to​ ​keep")
        print("track​ ​of​ ​mundane​ ​things​ ​like​ ​the​ ​date.")

    def get_today():
        the_date = input("Tell​ ​me,​ ​what​ ​day​ ​of​ ​the​ ​month​ ​is​ ​it​ ​today: ")

    say_words1()
    get_today()

main()
```

Hope it helps
---- Edit after comment:
As you still have the problem, you can try the workaround of inserting the string '\033[1A' that jumps 1 line up after the last sentence, as

```
print("track​ ​of​ ​mundane​ ​things​ ​like​ ​the​ ​date. \033[1A")
```

This is not a good solution as in my system the above code is not reproducing the problem, so the work-around creates the problem.

Comment: The line is still there.